# Считывание матрицы из файла C++

Tags: c++, матрицы

Хочу написать программу, которая выполняет матричные преобразования (сумма двух матриц, умножение, вычитание и т.д.), но застряла на этапе со считывнием матрицы. Выдает ошибку: "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. m.data было 0x1110112."
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//создаем структуру
struct Matrix {
    int** data = 0;
    size_t rows = 0;
    size_t cols = 0;
};

//функция, которая выделяет место для матрицы в динамической памяти и заполняет её
bool Allocate(Matrix& m) {
    //если матрица пустая, то заполняем её
    if (!m.data) {
        //выделяем место
        m.data = new int* [m.rows];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
            m.data[i] = new int[m.cols];
        }
        //заполняем нулями
        for (size_t y = 0; y < m.rows; y++) {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < m.cols; x++)
                m.data[x][y] = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//функция для удаления матрицы из памяти
bool Deallocate(Matrix& m) {
    if (m.data) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < m.rows; y++) {
            delete[] m.data[y];
        }
        delete[] m.data;
        m = Matrix();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//вывести матрицу
void outputMatrix(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& m) {
    out << m.rows << ' ' << m.cols << '\n';
    for (size_t y = 0; y < m.rows; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m.cols; x++) {
            out << m.data[y][x] << ' ';
        }
        out << '\n';
    }
}

//считывание матрицы из файла
bool inputMatrix(std::istream& in, Matrix& m) {
    Matrix result;
    //из первой строчки файла считываем количество строк и столбцов
    in >> result.rows >> result.cols;
    if (!result.rows || !result.cols) {
        std::cerr << "wrong\n";
        return false;
    }
    bool readResult = true;
    if (Allocate(result)) {
        //если мы создали матрицу
        for (size_t y = 0; y < result.rows; y++) {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < result.cols; x++) {
                //то итерируемся по строкам и столбцам
                if (readResult && in) {
                    //и если матрица считана, то заполняем матрицу значениями из файла
                    in >> m.data[x][y];
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "error reading matrix form\n";
                    readResult = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (readResult) {
        m = result;
    }
    else {
        Deallocate(m);
    }
    return readResult;
}

bool Sum(Matrix& dst, Matrix& lft, Matrix& rht) {
    if (lft.rows != rht.rows || lft.cols != rht.cols || (dst.data && (dst.rows != lft.rows || dst.cols != lft.cols))) {
        return false;
    }
    bool sumResult = true;
    Matrix result = dst;
    if (!dst.data) {
        result.rows = lft.rows;
        result.cols = lft.cols;
        sumResult = Allocate(result);
    }
    if (sumResult) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < result.rows; y++) {
            for (size_t x = 0; x < result.rows; x++) {
                result.data[x][y] = lft.data[y][x] + rht.data[y][x];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!Deallocate(result)) {
            std::cerr << "Error while deallocating memory\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return sumResult;
}

Matrix allocateAndRead(const char* filename) {
    Matrix result;
    std::ifstream fin(filename);
    if (!fin) {
        std::cerr << "error\n";
        return result;
    }
    if (inputMatrix(fin, result)) {
        outputMatrix(std::cout, result);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("input2.txt");
    if (!fin) {
        std::cerr << "error opening file\n";
        return 1;
    }
    Matrix m;
    if (inputMatrix(fin, m)) {
        outputMatrix(std::cout, m);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю - если уж С++, то почему не класс матрицы, а вот это вот все?...

Comment: Наверное читать нужно в `result`, а не в `m`...

Comment: Ещё какая-то путаница с индексами. Обращаясь к элементу матрицы в строке `y` и столбце `x` вы пишете то `data[y][x]`, то `data[x][y]`.